# Getting SSL handshake error while Enabling SSL in KAFKA

Tags: java, linux, rhel7

I’m getting SSL handshake failed when I start producer to push data, did below settings:

```
1. Followed steps as per 
    https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html to create keystore
2.  Started zookeeper with default settings
3.  Made below changes in kafka server properties:
    a.  listeners=SSL://hostName:9092
    b.  ssl.keystore.location =/home/kafka_2.12- 
       2.2.0/kafka.server.keystore.jks
    c.  ssl.keystore.password =keystore
    d.  ssl.key.password =keystore
    e.  ssl.truststore.location =/home/kafka_2.12- 
       2.2.0/kafka.server.truststore.jks
    f.  ssl.truststore.password =keystore
    g.  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
    h.  advertised.listeners=SSL://hostName:9092
    i.  inter.broker.listener.name=SSL
    j.  listener.security.protocol.map=SSL:SSL
```

After doing above steps, I was able to start kafka server and server got started.

```
Command bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "get /brokers/ids/0" gave below output that means broker id 0 was up and listening  on 
SSL://hostName:9092
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled
WATCHER::
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"SSL":"SSL"},"endpoints": 
["SSL://hostName:9092"]
 ,"jmx_port":-1,"host":null,"timestamp":"1559106754150" 
 ,"port":-1,"version":4}
cZxid = 0x425
ctime = Wed May 29 10:42:34 IST 2019
mZxid = 0x425
mtime = Wed May 29 10:42:34 IST 2019
pZxid = 0x425
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 1
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x1004d6fe052000a
dataLength = 159
numChildren = 0
```

But when I’m starting kafka producer to push data, I’m getting SSL handshake error on kafka server console

To start producer
    bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list hostName:9092 --topic test3

```
[2019-05-29 10:45:57,808] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-29 10:45:58,143] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-29 10:45:58,728] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-29 10:45:59,613] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-29 10:46:00,600] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-29 10:46:01,688] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2019-05-29 10:46:02,928] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed 
authentication with /101.101.101.101 (SSL handshake failed) 
(org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Note: Kafka broker server and producer are on same host

Expecting Producer should push data to broker which is running on same localhost.
Consumer from another node should be able to consume.
Data should be encrypted as we are enabling SSL

Answer (score -8):

was using single way handshaking.
Now got this issue resolved by implementing two way handshaking

Comment: Can you please write the detailed answer of how you have solved this?

Comment: It would be really useful if you tell us how did you fix it